# How to install a program remotely using Zentyal server and Windows7 clients

Tags: linux, windows-7, installation, zentyal

I'm using Zentyal in order to use it as Domain Controller.

All the clients are Windows7.

I, as domain admin, need to install, in several computers, one application that requires admin privileges.

How can I do it remotely and with one order for all computer clients?

Comment: I don't think Zentyal has support to deploy software to clients yet. They are working to improve desktop support in 3.0, so you may wish to check their [roadmap](http://trac.zentyal.org/milestone/3.0).

Comment: The link to the roadmap: http://forum.zentyal.org/index.php/topic,8767.0.html